# I am unable to update input value rendered with map method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an `input` value that I rendered using `map` method that I would like to update using `onChange` event and target the specific `input` field the user is typing on. My current solution updates all the rendered fields. How do I make this to work?
Here is my current code:

```
const  [customQuestionArrayLength, setCustomArrayLength] = useState<{checkBoxType: number, multipleQuestionType: number}>({checkBoxType: 1, multipleQuestionType: 1});//I can add more input fields by increasing the number value here

 const questionCustomArray:{answerValue: string}[] = new Array(customQuestionArrayLength.checkBoxType).fill({answerValue: ''});

const [checkBoxQuestionData, setCheckBoxQuestionData] = useState(questionCustomArray);


{
  checkBoxQuestionData.map((item, index)=>(
   <input type="text"}
     value={item.answerValue}
     name={item?.answerValue}
    onChange={(e)=> handleCheckQuestionArray(e.target.value, 'Checkbox_type', index) }
    />
))
 }
```

The function that updates it:

```
const handleCheckQuestionArray = (  text: string, eventType: 'Checkbox_type', indexPosition: number) =>{
    if(eventType === 'Checkbox_type'){
        if(typeof(indexPosition) === 'number' ){
                
            let result = [...checkBoxQuestionData];
            result.map((item, index)=>{
                    if(index === indexPosition){
                        return item.answerValue = text
                    }

                    return item
                })

                return setCheckBoxQuestionData(result);  
            }    
};
};
```